# CURL Access Denied

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Dears, I have issue started recently with my script;

I was using command `file_get_contents` with this URL:

> https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/notamRetrievalByICAOAction.do?method=displayByICAOs&formatType=ICAO&retrieveLocId=OEJN&reportType=RAW&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs

However, it stopped working since 2 weeks ago. I used modified headers but issue did not fix.

I switched to CURL and used following code:

```
$url='https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/notamRetrievalByICAOAction.do?method=displayByICAOs&formatType=ICAO&retrieveLocId=OEJN&reportType=RAW&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs';
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0';

/* getting data using cURL */
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$site = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $site;
```

I tried a lot of different headers but with no luck, I keep getting Access Denied.

If i visit the link via browser page will work. The weird part is that both ways are working when I run my script using local server (wampserver)!

Any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to specify additional options for dealing with SSL connections - such as `CURLOPT_CAINFO` and, most likely, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`

Comment: Are you sure you are not breaking one of their rules or usage policies

Comment: _"The weird part is that both ways are working when I run my script using local server (wampserver)!"_ - then your live server IP might have simply been blocked, due to unwanted scraping ...

Comment: https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/aboutsite.jsp: _"Although information presented within the U.S. NOTAM system is considered to be available for general public consumption, this web site is not designed for server level connections or screen scraping. Users seeking an automated method for obtaining NOTAMs may contact 7-AWA-NAIMES@faa.gov for information regarding Aeronautical Information Data Access Portal (AIDAP), an XML data feed for NOTAM and Weather information. To register for AIDAP, please access the FAA Data Registry at https://data.faa.gov/data/."_

Comment: I was registered in their system and it seems they changed something, I will contact them. Then issue is not code but by their side.